# Running filebeat setup fails

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, filebeat, elastic-beats

I installed Elasticsearch and Kibana on docker. I need to add Filebeat to the workflow, so I followed the official documentation [Run filebeat setup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html#_run_the_filebeat_setup)

I run this command:

```
docker run docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.1.2 setup -E setup.kibana.host=localhost:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["https://127.0.0.1:9200/"]
```

But I got this error :

> Exiting: couldn't connect to any of the configured Elasticsearch
> hosts. Errors: [error connecting to Elasticsearch at
> https://127.0.0.1:9200/: Get "https://127.0.0.1:9200/": dial tcp
> 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused]

I'm working with the current version of ELK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem, first I checked **elasticsearch.yml** and **kibana.yml**, I notice that the host address are not localhost,I also inspected both of the containers "**KIBANA** and **ELASTIC**" detail's and I found that they are pointing to the same host as yml file.

So run the command with the host adresses from the containers detail's and it worked :

```
docker run --net elastic -it docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:8.1.2  setup -E setup.kibana.host=172.18.0.3:5601 -E output.elasticsearch.hosts=["172.18.0.2:9200"]
```